# Ordenar un array de objetos tomando en cuenta el orden de los valores de otro array

Tags: javascript, array, ordenamiento

El problema es el siguiente:

Tengo un `array` de objetos, los cuales tienen propiedades `id` y `orden` (ambos enteros). Este `array` debo ordenarlo tomando en cuenta la propiedad `orden`, en función del orden de los valores que se encuentran en otro `array` de enteros.

Por ejemplo, si tengo el siguiente `array` de objetos:

```
objs = [
    { order: 1, id: 121 },
    { order: 2, id: 122 },
    { order: 3, id: 123 },
    { order: 4, id: 124 },
    { order: 5, id: 125 },
]
```

Y un `array` con los valores del orden deseado:

```
orden = [5, 3, 2, 4, 1]
```

El resultado de ordenar el primer `array` debería ser:

```
objs = [
    { order: 5, id: 125 },
    { order: 3, id: 123 },
    { order: 2, id: 122 },
    { order: 4, id: 124 },
    { order: 1, id: 121 },
]
```

Este es el código para mostrar los elementos del `array` `orden`:

```
orden.forEach((el, i) => {
    console.log(el);
});
```

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Si entendí bien, buscarías algo como esto:

```
let orden = [5, 3, 2, 4, 1]

let objs = [
    { order: 1, id: 121 },
    { order: 2, id: 122 },
    { order: 3, id: 123 },
    { order: 4, id: 124 },
    { order: 5, id: 125 },
]

let objsOrdenados = [];

// Ordenar
orden.forEach((elem1, i) =>
{
    objs.forEach((elem2, i) =>
    {
        if (elem2.order == elem1)
        {
            objsOrdenados.push(elem2);
        }
    });
});

// Listar con el nuevo order
objsOrdenados.forEach((elem3, i) =>
{
    console.log(elem3);
});
```

Comment: Hola Germán. Ya te comenté en otra publicacion sobre el contestar preguntas de baja calidad. Mira mi comentario de nuevo y considera dejar de responder esats preguntas asi como mejorar tus respuetas en cuanto a calidad.

Comment: Ok, ya entendi, pero no por eso hay que andar bajando puntos a cada rato

Comment: Es que si german. la reputacion es la base de este sitio, y seguir las reglas es una norma en el. Y tu reputacion es una cualidad de que tan responsable sos con el sitio...

Comment: simplemente no le vi ningun problema al planteo, pero esta bien tendre mas consideracion la proxima vez

Comment: Por si acaso, aclaro que mi voto negativo no es por responder una pregunta de baja calidad si no por la calidad de la respuesta

Answer (score 3):

Lo que debes de hacer primero es recorrer, el array donde tienes tu orden establecido. Y luego ir a buscar dentro de tu arreglo **objs** el item que tiene este orden.

Ahora, lo que hace el código es que hacemos un **map** sobre el array **orden** (recordemos que la función map crea un nuevo arreglo con los resultados mapeados).

Luego ya que tenemos un orden en cada iteración, debemos ir a buscar el object con este orden dentro de tu arreglo **objs** y para esto utilizamos la función **find**. La función find devuelve el primer elemento que cumpla la condición:

```
let items = orden.map(orden => {
  return objs.find(x => x.order === orden)
})
```

Te dejo acá un poco para que puedas leer más sobre map y find:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find

Saludos.

Comment: Hola Alex. Gracias por aportar, sin embargo, no siempre ha de responderse a preguntas. La pregunta ha de ser de calidad y clara. Lo recomendable es esperar a que se edite la pregunta para contestar. Mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus comentarios, lo tomare en cuenta en mis proximos aportes. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por entender. Un saludo

Comment: Si @lois6b soy nuevo por acá y quiero dar lo mejor para ayudar a los demas.

Comment: eso es genial. Solo recuerda que ayudar al sitio es mejor que ayudar a un solo usuario. Piensa que las preguntas y respuestas son para ayudar al usuario actual y a futuros usuarios con problemas similares. Este no puede extrapolarse pero si mostrara qué errores o problemas concretos tuvo, entonces si es válida

Answer (score 0):

[La respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/155285/) de [Germán](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/80967/) es buena, solo que entiendo faltó tomar en cuenta el index para que reordenar usando su código sea posible:

```
orden.forEach((elem1) =>
{
    objs.forEach((elem2, index) =>
    {
        if (elem2.order == elem1)
        {
            objsOrdenados[index] = elem2;
        }
    });
});
```

Así debe funcionar y solo he tomado este código e intentado agregar algo que lo haga realizar el trabajo deseado, que es ordenar un array usando otro como referencia de orden.